# Using coordinates in a tikzset

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I try to pass two coordinates to a tikzset and plot a arrow between those points. However, it does not work. I guess it's because of the interpretation of the coordinates.
The result of my MWE is wrong;

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  pics/somearrow/.style 2 args={
    code={
      %\coordinate (A) at {#1}; %%doesn't work either.
      %\coordinate (B) at {#2};
      %\draw [->] (A) -- (B);
      \draw [->] #1 -- #2;
    }}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);

  \foreach \from/\to in
  { {(0,0)}/{(3,3)},
    {(2,5)}/{(4,2)},
    {(4,4)}/{(2,5)}  }
  { \pic at \from {somearrow={\from}{\to}}; }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]
(I'm very new to tikz.)

Comment: Can't you just do something like `\foreach \from/\to in {{w,x}/{y,z}} {\draw[->] (\from) -- (\to);}`? Why use a `pic` here at all?

Comment: TikZ has special code for loops over coordinates. See the manual for the gory details.

Comment: The arrow are just a placeholder for something more involving.
cfr, I only found foreach. Can you give a keyword, what to look for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the origin of the `pic` is at that point where it is inserted. So in `{ \pic at \from {somearrow={\from}{\to}}; }` both arguments are relatively to the `at \from`.

To get

[image]

you could use

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  pics/somearrow/.style 2 args={
    code={
      \draw [->] #1 -- #2;
    }}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);

  \foreach \from/\to in
  { {(0,0)}/{(3,3)},
    {(2,5)}/{(4,2)},
    {(4,4)}/{(2,5)}% the % is here important
  }
  { \pic at (0,0) {somearrow={\from}{\to}}; }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  pics/somearrow/.style={
    code={
      \draw [->] (0,0) -- #1;
    }}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);

  \foreach \from/\to in
  { {(0,0)}/{(3,3)},
    {(2,5)}/{(2,-3)},
    {(4,4)}/{(-2,1)}% the % is here important
  }
  { \pic at \from {somearrow=\to}; }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why is the % important?

Comment: @dani You will get an error if there are spaces after `{(...)}`. There should be also no space before the commas or around the `/` inside the list.